# How to copy a text array to a series of cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am dynamically creating a report, where I create a worksheet, bring in the records afresh.  How can I easily type the field names and copy them to the cells. Without doing one cell per line, there are ~20 columns.

I tried:

```
dim fieldNames as variant
fieldNames = ("'DS Date', 'A', 'B', 'A','S ASD', 'S','D S','D S', 'S','D S', 'SD', 'S','D'")
Sheets("DATA").Range("C14:W14").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(fieldNames)
```

But it just posts the whole thing in each cell? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are hard coding the array, try something more like this:

```
Dim fieldNames As Variant
fieldNames = Array("DS Date", "A", "B", "A", "S ASD", "S", "D S", "D S", "S", "D S", "SD", "S", "D")
Sheets("DATA").Range("C14:W14").Value = fieldNames
```

Here's a [reference on using Array()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) it's for VB6, but it's still correct.

EDIT: I did some tinkering, and you could also accomplish about the same thing by changing your last line to this:

```
Sheets("DATA").Range("C14:W14").FormulaArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(fieldNames, ",")))
```

This method transposes the horizontal array to vertical and then back again, but uses Transpose like you were doing. :-D Of course this method doesn't really make since considering we could have just put `Split(fieldNames, ",")` down directly. Like this: `Sheets("Data").Range("C14:W14").value = Split(fieldNames, ",")` not sure why I gave you a complicated example first.

Comment: Thanks, it's the little things you forget to put like 'array', LMAO.